# Flow and pressure of a fluid in a open setup vs. closed setup

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

I have two mostly identical setups A and B.

[image: Setups A and B]

Both consist of the following:

1. Pump
2. Pressure Sensors
3. Manually operated flow restriction valve
4. Elastic tubing
5. Flow Sensor
6. Open water basin (only in setup A)

So the only difference is the open water basin the tubes go into in setup A vs. connected tubing in setup B. For both setups the tubing lengths and diameters stay the same.
The pump can only be turned on/off without any fine tuning.
I know the pump will deliver less flow with higher pressure head across the setup.
The pump (1) is now operated and the valve (3) adjusted to create a steady pressure head of 1 bar between the two pressure sensors (2). The resulting steady flow is measured with the flow sensor (5).
In setup A the resulting flow is substancially less (~10%) than in setup B.

Why is that? I would assume that if I have the same pressure with the same pump, the flow must be the same.

Comment: please, provide some values. Do you have the characteristic curve of the pump? Or other details on the technical sheet?

Comment: I don't have characteristics of the pump. I only know that increasing pressure head will decrease the flow. So it seems I am increasing the pressure head by using setup A. Somehow this pressure head cannot be measured using my pressure sensors.